# How can i write the below php code in javascript.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hi i am working on converting a php application to continue billing even internet is not working. So i am converting the php codes to javascript. In between i got stuck at an area where my billing ends. Here i need to group the similar tax % to one. Can someone let me know how can it be done ?

```
$new_result = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tax] => SGST@2.5%
            [percent] => 2.38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tax] => CGST@2.5%
            [percent] => 2.38
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tax] => CGST@9%
            [percent] => 15.25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tax] => SGST@9%
            [percent] => 15.25
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tax] => SGST@2.5%
            [percent] => 3.57
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [tax] => CGST@2.5%
            [percent] => 3.57
        )

)   

     $out = array();
        foreach ($new_result as $key => $value){
            if (array_key_exists($value['tax'], $out)){
                $out[$value['tax']]['percent'] += ', '+$value['percent'];
            } else {
               $out[$value['tax']] = array('tax' => $value['tax'], 'percent' => $value['percent']);
            }
        }
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tax] => SGST@2.5%
            [percent] => 5.95
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tax] => CGST@2.5%
            [percent] => 5.95
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tax] => CGST@9%
            [percent] => 15.25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tax] => SGST@9%
            [percent] => 15.25
        )

)
```

My try :

```
    var out = [];
    $.each(new_result, function(key,value5) {
        if(value5.tax in out){
            //
        }else{
            out[value5.tax] = [{tax:value5.tax, percent:value5.percent}];
        }
    });
```

Input array

```
var newresult = [{"tax":"CGST@9%","percent":"76.27"},{"tax":"SGST@9%","percent":"76.27"},{"tax":"CGST@9%","percent":"15.25"},{"tax":"SGST@9%","percent":"15.25"},{"tax":"SGST@2.5%","percent":"3.57"},{"tax":"CGST@2.5%","percent":"3.57"}];
```

Comment: I want to group them based on the percentage value. And frankly i don't know that php snippet. it was done by previous developer

Comment: The PHP output you give does not correspond to the PHP code you have given. It would produce an associative array, not one with numerical indexes.

Comment: Also your PHP concatenates percentages, which is not anywhere present in your output. Could you please fix your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you can use `reduce` function like below to group

```js
var gst = [
  {tax: 'SGST@2.5%', percent: 2.38},
  {tax: 'CGST@2.5%', percent: 2.38},
  {tax: 'CGST@9%', percent: 15.25},
  {tax: 'SGST@9%', percent: 15.25},
  {tax: 'SGST@2.5%', percent: 3.57},
  {tax: 'CGST@2.5%', percent: 3.57}
];

var result = gst.reduce(function (acc, ele) {
  var index = acc.findIndex(e => e.tax == ele.tax);
  if (index == -1) {
    acc.push({
      tax: ele.tax,
      percent: ele.percent
    })
  } else {
    acc[index].percent += parseFloat(ele.percent);
    acc[index].percent = acc[index].percent;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When i constantly add 3 product of same tax group this code fails to add the percentage.

Comment: @SarathHari, you can post the different question with the issue you are facing, then all SO guys and I can see that ;-)

Comment: But issue is in this same code bro @JavascriptLover-SKT

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: acc[index].percent.toFixed is not a function

Comment: Today is this project submission and i am still stuck in office

Comment: @SarathHari can you please come the discussion room which is mentioned in the first comment of this answer

Comment: @SarathHari Okay that's fine. That is to fix the decimals after the point. can you please come to the chat once? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180719/discussion-on-answer-by-javascript-lover-skt-how-can-i-write-the-below-php-cod

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of objects in javascript (`newResult`), you can use `reduce()` function to produce the `out` array:

```js
let newResult = [
   {
      tax: 'CGST@2.5%',
      percent: 2.38 
   },
   {
      tax: 'SGST@2.5%',
      percent: 2.38
   },
   {
      tax: 'CGST@2.5%',
      percent: 15.25
   },
   {
      tax: 'SGST@2.5%',
      percent: 3.57
   }
];

let out = newResult.reduce((acc, val) => {
   let existing = acc.filter((p) => p.tax === val.tax);
   if (existing.length === 1) {
      existing[0].percent += val.percent;
   } else {
      acc.push(val);
   }   
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do the same by using JS as well,

```
    var myArray = [
  {tax: 'SGST@2.5%', percent: 2.38},
  {tax: 'CGST@2.5%', percent: 2.38},
  {tax: 'CGST@9%', percent: 15.25},
  {tax: 'SGST@9%', percent: 15.25},
  {tax: 'SGST@2.5%', percent: 3.57},
  {tax: 'CGST@2.5%', percent: 3.57}
];

var groups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var groupName = myArray[i].tax;
  if (!groups[groupName]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
  groups[groupName].push(myArray[i].percent);
}
myArray = [];
for (var groupName in groups) {
  myArray.push({group: groupName, tax: groups[groupName]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP output you give in your question does not correspond to the PHP code which you have given. That code would produce an associative array, where the keys are the tax codes, and the values would be comma separated strings. I will assume the code is correct and the PHP output is not.

In JavaScript you best translate PHP associative arrays to plain objects (or in ES6 you could use `Map`). With a plain object a quite literal conversion to JavaScript would look like this:

```js
const newResult = [
    { tax: 'SGST@2.5%', percent:  2.38 },
    { tax: 'CGST@2.5%', percent:  2.38 },
    { tax: 'CGST@9%',   percent: 15.25 },
    { tax: 'SGST@9%',   percent: 15.25 },
    { tax: 'SGST@2.5%', percent:  3.57 },
    { tax: 'CGST@2.5%', percent:  3.57 }
];

const out = {}; // <== object
for (const value of newResult) {
    if (!(value.tax in out)) {
       out[value.tax] = Object.assign({}, value); // This copies all property values
    } else {
        out[value.tax].percent += ", " + value.percent; // Converts number to string
    }
}

console.log(out);
```

I would personally prefer to create `percent` values as arrays instead of comma separated strings when there is more than one matching percentage, but since you already made that choice in PHP I left it like that in JS also. I find it problematic that the way you did it, you're left with `percent` values that sometimes are numeric (when there is no aggregation) and sometimes are string (when multi-valued). Again, I leave this like you had it in PHP.

Comment: The output is what i got when i printed and your answer have percentage as comma separated